# Error while running cmd command in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I want to run some command prompt command from my ASP  page.
I wrote something like this and it is working.

```
dim wShell1 : Set wShell1 = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim cmd1 : set cmd1 = wShell1.Exec("hostname") 
dim output1 : output1 = cmd1.StdOut.Readall()
response.write(output1)
set cmd1 = nothing
Set wShell1 = nothing
```

But when I change the command from "hostname" to "cc c_filename.c" it is giving me error. Basically I want to compile this c file from asp code itself. 
Anybody knows what is going wrong.

The exception I am getting is:
"WshShell.Exec: The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: what is "cc" ? your app name? in what folder it's located? does IUSR_xxx user has access (read and execute permission) to this file?

Comment: "cc" is the name of the compiler I am using to compile my c file and "c_filename.c" is the c file name that I wrote. "cc" is a compiler from Dev-Cpp . I am able to compile using "cc" from command prompt . It's full path is also set in environment variable.  Any Idea what's going wrong.

Comment: does IUSR_xxx user has access (read and execute permission) to this file?